# Oracle SQLPlus question - writing strings to txt file

Tags: sql, oracle, file, sqlplus

I am attempting to write an sql command into an sql file so that the output itself can be used as a script.  Basically using a script to create output that is itself formatted into runnable script.  Maybe it's redundant but I haven't been able to think of a better way.  I could use an extra set of eyes (or ideas) if possible.  Thanks

Here's the script:

```
CONNECT &&master_user/&&master_pwd.@&&tns_alias
SET LINESIZE 132 PAGESIZE 0 ECHO OFF FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF HEAD OFF TERM OFF TRIMSPOOL ON
SPO syns_list.sql
--GRANT CREATE ANY SYNONYM TO &&syn_user;//how is this line formed?
select  'create or replace synonym ' || table_name ||
' for ' || '&&master_user..' ||
table_name || ';'
from user_tables
order by table_name asc;
--REVOKE CREATE ANY SYNONYM FROM &&syn_user;//how is this line formed?
SPO OFF;
SET ECHO ON FEEDBACK ON VERIFY ON HEAD ON TERM ON;
exit
```

This is the output:

```
//need the "grant" line here
create or replace synonym AGENTS for webdemo_admin.AGENTS;
create or replace synonym CONSTRUCTION_COMPANY for webdemo_admin.CONSTRUCTION_COMPANY;
create or replace synonym CONTRACT for webdemo_admin.CONTRACT;
create or replace synonym CUSTOMERS for webdemo_admin.CUSTOMERS;
create or replace synonym CUSTOMER_INTEREST for webdemo_admin.CUSTOMER_INTEREST;
create or replace synonym FEATURE for webdemo_admin.FEATURE;
create or replace synonym HOME for webdemo_admin.HOME;
create or replace synonym HOME_NONSTD_FEATURE for webdemo_admin.HOME_NONSTD_FEATURE;
create or replace synonym INTEREST for webdemo_admin.INTEREST;
create or replace synonym NON_STD_FEATURE for webdemo_admin.NON_STD_FEATURE;
create or replace synonym SALES for webdemo_admin.SALES;
create or replace synonym STD_FEATURE for webdemo_admin.STD_FEATURE;
create or replace synonym STD_MODEL for webdemo_admin.STD_MODEL;
create or replace synonym STD_MODEL_FEATURE for webdemo_admin.STD_MODEL_FEATURE;
create or replace synonym SUB_CONTRACTOR for webdemo_admin.SUB_CONTRACTOR;
create or replace synonym WARRANTY_WORK for webdemo_admin.WARRANTY_WORK;
//need the "revoke" line here
```

I am sure there are better ways to do this, I'm still picking things up as I go.  As fo an explanation (for understanding):  I want that I maintain a user with full control over the tables (and the schema) but I need a user (or upto 10 users) with the above-listed private synonyms in order for multiple connections to have the same type of access that a real-estate agent might (when viewing this from the perspective of a web app).  That is, the synonyms allow for select,insert, update and delete transactions.  The reason for the grant/revoke before and after the synonym creation is only to automate the process and remove the security problem of granting the create any synonym to a normal user.  Further, I do not want the synonyms to be public as that is also a headache to keep track of (and again a security problem).  In any case, private is better and offers more control.

Again, I appreciate any suggestions anyone may have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the SQL*Plus `PROMPT` keyword what you're after?  This just displays the rest of the line:

```
SQL> DEFINE syn_user = exampleuser1234
SQL> PROMPT GRANT CREATE ANY SYNONYM TO &&syn_user;;
GRANT CREATE ANY SYNONYM TO exampleuser1234;
SQL>
```

Note that we must double the semicolon since SQL*Plus interprets the first one as the end of the substitution parameter `syn_user`.

Comment: that did it.  "PROMPT" was the keyword I was missing.  Works great now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to run the generated script as the synonym owner, which appears to be the case, it shouldn't need `CREATE ANY SYNONYM` privilege, just `CREATE SYNONYM` privilege.  I would just grant that privilege when creating the user.

To do a grant in this script, you'd need to first connect as a privileged user, such as SYSTEM.  In that case, you might as well run the whole things as SYSTEM, which already has `CREATE ANY SYNONYM`.  To do that you would just need to modify your create statements to include the owner of the synonym, e.g. `create or replace synonym <syn_user>.STD_MODEL_FEATURE for webdemo_admin.STD_MODEL_FEATURE;` (where `<syn_user>` is the value of the `&syn_user` substitution variable).

(To clarify, those are two different ways of approaching it.  Pick one or the other, not both.)

Comment: Went with: `select  'create or replace synonym &&syn_user..' || table_name || ' for ' || '&&master_user..' || table_name || ';' from user_tables order by.  What threw meoff was that there was no prompt for the syn_user variable.  Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, the prompt for the variable winds up in the created script file.

Comment: @Jinx3y -- Sorry, I didn't mean that you should generate the script with the substitution variable in it.  I was just showing where it would go in the generated command.  I'll try to improve it.